# How to build intermediate CA server detailly using fabric ca?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

From [Enrolling intermediate ca](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/users-guide.html#enrolling-an-intermediate-ca),must specify “hf.IntermediateCA = true, and

```
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -u http://<enrollmentID>:<secret>@<parentserver>:<parentport>
```

,while I am fail to build intermediate ca server .

Could somebody give the detail steps?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you launch root ca (localhost:7054) and intermediate ca (localhost:8054) on localhost.

Firstly, you should register identity with *hf.IntermediateCA=true* attribute by root ca. For example:

```
fabric-ca-client register --id.name ica --id.attrs '"hf.Registrar.Roles=user,peer",hf.Revoker=true,hf.IntermediateCA=true' --id.secret icapw
```

Secondly, open intermediate ca home directory and initialize the intermediate ca:

```
fabric-ca-server init -b icaadmin:icaadminpw -u http://ica:icapw@localhost:7054
```

Change port of intermediate ca (8054) and some other settings of intermediate ca in *fabric-ca-server-config.yaml* file.

After that, you can start intermediate ca:

```
fabric-ca-server start
```

Comment: Thank you.It works. But notice：1. localhost must replace the true ip address, because intermediate ca connect to the real ca server 2. annotation the intermediate ca server_config.yaml  csr.name field.

Comment: @JimGreen yes, you should set the real ip address of root ca